Visual Studio - Can't edit secrets.json file
I open my Visual Studio project and the secrets.json file is already open but I can't edit it.  I can move the cursor around on the page but I can't edit anything.

For some reason it shows another tab (in my case launchSettings.json) being edited even though I'm not on that tab.  If I click on the other tab, then click back to the secrets.json, I can now edit it.  You may find the other tab now has strange edits you probably want to remove.
